# Is there a way to refresh/regenerate AirDrop random hash keys present in the Preferences file com.apple.sharingd.plist?

Tags: bluetooth, plist, airdrop

Is there a way to refresh/regenerate AirDrop (are them the same/shared with the Bluetooth service?) random hash keys present in the Preferences file: `com.apple.sharingd.plist`?

```
/Users/userMe/Library/Preferences
```

This (xml) format file, contains at least 4 hashes in this format (example for Key1):

```
<key>AirDropRandomHashUUIDKey1</key>
<string>the_hash</string>
```

File also ends with unidentified 8 long hashes (Bluetooth? AirDrop?).